# document creator as username or userId

Tags: meteor

In a meteor collection for a document I have a creator attribute. Is it advisable to store the username (more intuitive) or userId (which is user._id) as creator attribute? What is the more standard practice?

Comment: this is sort of a subjective question, so I'll post by opinion as a comment: I use `user._id`, both because it is already taken care of to be unique, and because it allows users to change their name (just like on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With document databases, the answer is commonly, "both".

Storing the `userId` is required as it is the only field that is guaranteed to not change (as others have pointed out).

It's often worth it to store "denormalized" data as well.  In some cases, its actually required.

Take for example a line item on an invoice.  It needs to be static, a snapshot in time.  You'd need to store the product info at the time of the purchase even though later that product's name or other characteristic may be changed by the vendor.

In our app, there are times when we store user profile info (name, contact info, etc) in addition to the userId.  In some cases its strictly for performance reasons, in others its a snapshot used in audit reporting and must not change.

In the performance case, you'll probably want to have processes in place to update the "denormalized" data if it is ever changed in the "source of authority".  In the snapshot case, like invoice line-items, you'll want to explicitly *not* update them.  Sometimes, its just ok for the data to be out-of-date and its not worth the complexity of keeping it updated.

For a good example of this kind of "document vs relational" design discussion, check out these two blogs posts:

- http://ayende.com/blog/4465/that-no-sql-thing-the-relational-modeling-anti-pattern-in-document-databases
- http://ayende.com/blog/4466/that-no-sql-thing-modeling-documents-in-a-document-database

Answer (score 2):

I always join collections by id, and I'd advise you to do the same. The id will never change, but the underlying data may be altered. In this example, if the user changes his/her username then the join would be broken.

Comment: This was an interesting question and answer for me since I'm trying to unlearn my relational background while learning meteor's take at docs/collections where it is not always in line with stock meteor advice. Having said that, is it not sometimes considered better to include the required attribute instead of an id, in order to reduce db roundtrips? For example "tags" on a post where a) the underlying data is less likely to be changed and b) is queried very often, while c) uniqueness is not much of a concern. What's your take on this?

Comment: I have a lot more to say about this than a comment will allow, but I think the denormalization section of [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/) post sums it up nicely. I'll say, I think mongodb was a nice choice for meteor only because of it's interface. I think storing data relationally is generally the best choice even though this goes against mongodb best practices... but there are exceptions to every rule.

Comment: That's kind of my gut feeling as well. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

A couple reasons why you would use User._id over a username

- User._id's are more URL friendly (no UTF-8, other languages etc.)
- User._id is static
- Mongo and Minimongo is good at finding and updating Collections with an _id

Answer (score 0):

The best reason to use the _id from the users collection is that all meteor methods and publish functions provide `this.userId` to identify the user who made the call.  That `userId` is the only information you have about who is making the client request.

If you use username or some other unique field in `Meteor.users` you will always need to look up the user by id to get the other field.